# I want to make a program in which when I press the button the text changes

Tags: java, android

It is an android app.

Text is stored in an array. It should change  serial wise

Here is what I had done before.

```
String name = "";
String names[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
int counter = 0;
name = names[counter];
counter++;
if(counter >= 3)
{
   counter = 0;
}
return name;
```

I was doing something like that before. I know it totally incorrect . But something like this I wanted to do.

Comment: Ok. And what's your question? What have you tried to solve this? What went wrong?

Comment: Your question is too broad.  What are you asking about in particular?

Comment: Where is you bug ? Where is your code ? We can help you to debug your code, not code the program for you

Comment: `Ctrl+C` ? How could you run this program on a phone ? It should be the native C++ program then.

Comment: OOps that was a typo sorry fixed that

Answer (score 1):

This may help solve your problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    static int currentIndex = 0;
    static String[] words = {"word1", "word2", "word3"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(input != null){
                System.out.println(words[currentIndex++]);
                if(currentIndex == words.length){
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```